# Detecting grid orientation and properties

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have a collection of many points arranged in a uniform grid-like fashion. Given these points, how do I detect properties of this grid, such as it's rotation, spacing between lines, etc? If there was some algorithm to fit many parallel and perpendicular lines to this data, then I could average the distance between lines, angle, and so on and so forth. What is the best way to do this?

**UPDATE:**
The data that I'm working with looks roughly like this:

[image]

It will be cleaner in the future, but I just need some way to interpolate and analyze that grid like pattern.

Comment: What does the grid look like? If it's rectangular then the solution will be easier.

Comment: It is indeed rectangular. I'm working with data that looks like this
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~schmatz/grid.jpg

Comment: If you can actually shape the grid and guarantee its a rectangle, the the top-left point will be the closest distance to the origin (assumed to be the top-left of the image). The bottom-right point will be the furthest distance from the origin. You can form a line between these two points; the point furthest from this line will be either the bottom-left or top-right point in the grid. With these points you can calculate the rotation of the grid. You can see how I used this in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604485/sorting-2d-points-into-a-matrix/15604867#15604867

Comment: Is the image the only thing you have? Do you have (x,y) coordinates of each grid point?

Answer (score 1):

If the points are placed on a grid, then the squared distance between 2 points is *d*²×(*m*² + *n*²) where *d* is the grid constant (assume that it is a 2D rectangular grid with the same constant in both principal directions), and *m*, *n* are integer numbers defining the (affine) difference between the two points (or, simpler, the number of grid intervals between the two points along the "x" and "y" axes) So:

- compute the squared distances between a point and all other points;
- by dividing them to the minimum one, you'll get rational numbers that give you hints about the grid constant *d* and the relative "coordinates" *m*, *n*.

Comment: Thanks! This really should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only image of the grid, you may try `radon` function from "Image processing toolbox". It will give you angles and from radon transform you can recalculate distance between lines of points on your image.

Here is a code sample for `radon` function

```
% First we generate a grid of points on image
ImgW        = 400;
ImgH        = 300;
DIdx                    = ImgH + round(rand(1)*ImgH/10);
ImgGrid                 = zeros(ImgH,ImgW);
ImgGrid(1:DIdx:end)     = 1;

% Then we calculate radon transform
theta                   = 0:0.1:180;
[R,xp]                  = radon(ImgGrid,theta);

% Then we calculate standard deviation for each angle of R
Rstd                    = std(R);
% and find maximal value of std(R) columnwise
[RstdMax,RstdIdx]       = max(Rstd);
ThMax                   = theta(RstdIdx);

% Now we show results
figure('Color','w');
subplot(2,2,1);     imshow( ImgGrid );
                    axis on;
                    colormap(hot(255));
                    title('Grid image');
                    line( ImgW/2+[-1 +1]*min(ImgW,ImgH)/2*cosd(-ThMax), ...
                          ImgH/2+[-1 +1]*min(ImgW,ImgH)/2*sind(-ThMax), 'Color','y' );
subplot(2,2,3);     plot(xp,R(:,RstdIdx),'.-');
                    title(sprintf('Profile at %.2f deg (the yellow line)',ThMax));

subplot(2,2,2);     imagesc( log10(R+1), 'Xdata',theta, 'Ydata',xp );
                    axis on;
                    colormap(hot(255));
                    xlabel('\theta (degrees)');
                    ylabel('x''');

subplot(2,2,4);     plot(theta,Rstd,'.-');
                    title('std(R)');
```

**BUT** in general case this will not give you lattice vectors for the grid! This will give you only distance between lines of points instead. If you need lattice vectors you have to recalculate them. But if you are lucky enough and your lattice is rectangular... hope you got the point ;o)

You are even more lucky if you have (x,y) coordinates of your points. The approach that ***CST-Link*** proposed is somewhat "too brute-force". I'd rather calculate the "structure factor" for your points (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_factor and the tutorial links at the end of the article) and analyzed its maxima.

Answer (score 0):

If you have each point's coordinates, things might be not so complicated.

It might be a good idea to do a [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) on those coordinates.
The first principal component will be the axis along of the longer side of your grid, the second principal component will be the axis of the shorter side.

With those new axes, you could run a [sweep-line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) along the principal axis, which will allow you to assign a row-number to each point. Another sweep along the second axis will allow you to assign a column-number.